# How to mix 2 colors smoothly with OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, opencv3.0

I try to use OpenGL to draw a mask frame overlay input frame.

A mask frame is a lip shape with red color.

A input frame is a face.

When i drew, i recognized it is not smoothly.

I need suggest some keywords or solution.

This is my code.

```
 uniform sampler2D input_frame;
 uniform sampler2D overlay;
 uniform vec3 target_color;

   void main() {
 vec4 image_pix = texture2D(input_frame, sample_coordinate);
 vec4 overlay_pix = texture2D(overlay, sample_coordinate);
 vec4 color2 = vec4(target_color, 1.0);

 float luminance = dot(image_pix.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
 float mix_value = overlay_pix.r * luminance;
 fragColor = mix(image_pix, color2, mix_value);
}
```

This is my result:
[image]

This is my target:
[image]

Comment: You can achieve a smooth effect by fading the lips towards the edges in the overlay texture.